# Django - Automatic task performace at specific time

Tags: django

My app consists of posts with upvote counter.
I would like to set automatic task for Django to zero upvote counter for each post at midnight.

What is the best way to achieve it? Is there any built-in or external libraries for such purposes?

Answer (score 2):

Python schedule is best for Scheduling functions

runs function at midnight everyday:

```py
schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(function_name)
```

for  a particular day :(only runs on tuesday at 18:00)

```py
schedule.every().tuesday.at("18:00").do(function_name)
```